# I want to minimize the app on pressing backbutton on Android devices in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-router-flux

If my navigation stack is empty, I want to minimize the application on android devices. For now it doesn't do anything. I am using the code below for back button handling.

```
 componentDidMount () {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.backAndroid()) // Listen for the hardware back button on Android to be pressed
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => this.backAndroid()) // Remove listener
  }

  backAndroid () {
    Actions.pop() // Return to previous screen
    return true // Needed so BackHandler knows that you are overriding the default action and that it should not close the app
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing you can try is to write the following function in a native-module and call it through your JavaScript file:

```
@ReactMethod
void minimizeApp() {

    getCurrentActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);


}
```

Also Don't forget to add the following line in MainActivity of `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Comment: what about expo?